# Определить размерность типа int на контроллере

Tags: c, embedded

Можно ли написать какую-нибудь функцию, чтобы узнать размерность типа `int` на конкретном контроллере?

Comment: printf("size of int is %d\n", sizeof(int));

Comment: а можно и запустить функцию i++ и когда (i > i+1) вывести значение.

Comment: Только учтите, что `sizeof()` дает размер не в байтах, а в количестве элементов типа `char` (в большинстве случаев они совпадают с размером в 8-битных байтах).

Размер типа `char` в битах определяется в `<limits.h>` и называется   `CHAR_BIT`.

Т.о. количество бит в `int` надо вычислять так

       sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT

В том же файле определены константы, описывающие максимальное и минимальное значение для различных целых типов. 

--

Впрочем, используя известные битовые операци, они мгновенно вычисляются. Например, INT_MAX:

       int int_max_value = ((unsigned)(~0)) >> 1;

Comment: sizeof(int) говорит 4. ((unsigned)(~0)) >> 1 говорит 0x7FFFFFFF (тоже 4?).
регистры у контроллера 32битные (согласно даташиту), из этого предполагаю, что и int у него 4битный
всем спасибо!

Comment: @cat_bug, Вы разницу между *количеством* бит и *значением целого числа*, которое может быть представлено этими битами ощущаете?

--

Еще раз -- количество бит типа `int`:

      sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT

Константа `CHAR_BIT` в нормальных ОС определена в `<limits.h>`.

Comment: Если уж Вам в самом деле приперло динамически определять размер GPR (РОН) в битах, то 


    int 
    gpr_bitsize () 
    {
      register long lr = -1LL;
      int l = 0;
    
      while (lr <<= 1)
        l++;
    
      return l + 1;
    }
    
можно так.

Comment: @avp: `unsigned long`? (ну и [как обычно](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4240878/276994))

Comment: @avp: В общем случае это UB: [[1]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4240878/276994), [[2]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9867883/276994). Так что мы тем самым избегаем ненужной зависимости от GCC.

---
Ну и тогда инициализировать не минус, а плюс единицей.

---
Исправил ссылку: [[2]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3784996/276994).

Comment: @VladD, комментарии кончились, предыдущий


    поскольку сдвигаем влево, то IMHO без разницы.

пришлось уже удалять...


Согласен, инициализировать 1 (а не -1LL) лучше (понятнее). А в целом результат все равно будет тем же.

Comment: @avp `sizeof` возвращает размер именно в байтах. А вот сколько *бит* в байте это уже другой вопрос. `sizeof(char) == 1` по определению, т.е. `char` всегда занимает 1 байт. Поэтому фраза "размер не в байтах, а в количестве элементов типа `char`" сама себе противоречит.

Comment: @alexolut, некоторые ребята из TI, говорят, что у них в TMS 8-битные байты, а вот минимально адресуемая единица -- 4-x байтный `char`. В общем, похоже единой терминологии тут нет.

Comment: @avp я в своем ответе опирался на текст Стандарта по С99 6.5.3.4/2: "The `sizeof` operator yields the size (**in bytes**) of its operand". И терминология оттуда же.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно посчитать кол-во бит в байте,

```
int CharBit() {
    unsigned char c = ~0U;
    int res = 1;
    for(; c >>= 1; ++res) {}
    return res;
}
```

а дальше (sizeof(int) * CharBit()). То есть кол-во char'ов и int'е умножить на кол-во битов в char'e равно кол-ву битов в int'e. Для x86: 4 * 8 = 32

Вот ещё:

```
int IntBit() {
    int tmp = 0, res = 0; // 0xfffff...
    while(++res, tmp >>= 1) {}
    return res;
}
```

Comment: А что это за `constexpr`? (тем более в Си) Да и вообще, `res` надо бы инициализировать не нулем, а 1.

Comment: да вы правы! sorry! поправил!